# Is there a NAS that can act as a "simple", "dumb" USB Drive?

Tags: networking, usb, nas, local

I have a satellite video reciever that can store (save) movies on an attched USB hard disk (FAT32 or NTFS). I there an NAS-System out there that can act as a dumb hard disk attached via USB towards the video reciever??

Whhat I am looking for is a NAS that my satellite reciever will accpept as a hard drive. At the same time I want to address the NAS "nomally" via my local area network. Basically I want to "trick" the reciever into storing files that I can access from the network.

I this idea totally "off the wall"?

Comment: The problem with this is that a NAS is NETWORK attached storage, which you want to use as LOCAL (non-network) attached storage. While there might be something out there that works you should search for another term (e.g. on "USB attached HDD". Not on "NAS").

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

The problem with what you're trying to do is that you would be letting the satellite receiver write to the file system (and partition tables) of the drive while also letting the processor of the NAS device to the same thing. Even if you could persuade the video receiver and NAS devices to let you do this, you'd probably have a corrupt file system before the end of the day.

You may have been fooled into thinking this was viable by certain advanced enterprise storage systems wherein two servers were both connected by SCSI to a single disk storage system. In this situation, there was a 'heartbeat' monitoring system that would lock a system out of the disk if it failed and hand the disk over to the backup server. That is a very different situation, as there was no moment when both servers had control of the disk.